# Should Objective-C header include #ifndef macro?

Tags: objective-c, macos, header

Currently, if I create a header file in Xcode, it creates one with

```
#ifndef Types_h
#define Types_h

// ..
```

But if I create a Cocoa class, then the header generated is of the form

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN
// ..
```

Is `#ifndef` not required in the later case? Does Objective-C automatically include only headers once?

Answer (score -1):

If `#ifndef Types_h` is not present then if you import the same header multiple times in a file it will declare the same macros multiple times that are declared in Type.h file

Comment: No, not, if you import a file. Tis can happen only, if you include a file.